# C# MySQL parameter not working

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, parameters

Apparently my parameter doesn't seem to be working (C# ASP.NET). My code throws an exception at `comm.ExecuteScalar()`.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'' at line 1'
```

this is my source code:

```
public int countRows(string table)
    {
        string cmdString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tbl";
        int count = -1;

        using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandText = cmdString;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl", "users");
            count = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Yet when i use this it works perfectly fine:

```
public int countRows(string table)
    {
        string cmdString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
        int count = -1;

        using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            comm.Connection = conn;
            comm.CommandText = cmdString;
            count = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        return count;
    }
```

This has been driving me crazy for hours now. Anyone who could help me out?

Comment: @MethodMan so no safe way to prevent SQL injection with free input?

Comment: @murdoch  you can't use parameters for either table or column names

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

`string cmdString = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", table);`